# slow adb pull/push

Tags: adb, file-transfer, data-transfer, mtp

On my previous arch linux install the `adb pull/push` worked at a speed of around 25mbps. Recently I recently reinstalled arch linux and since then the pull/push operation are working very slow, at around 10 mbps. The mtp transfers are working just fine. I suspect there might be a software bottleneck because the transfer speed with adb is constant at 10 mbps. I pushed and pulled a 481 mb file back and forth a couple of times and the time was always around 48.5 sec, differing at the fourth significant digit. What might cause the adb operations to slow down like that?

Comment: Yeah. BTW, if you have a custom recovery, try adb push/pull from there for once. You might get better speed but not at par with MTP. I don't know why though. // Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28314131/4720957